# How to visualize 3D model in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, 3d

I have hypsometric map/model of mountain which I get by contour lines with Z value. Can you explain how to visualize 3d model in ArcGIS? I need to get something like nviz command in GRASS.

Comment: what format is your model in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to fire up either ArcScene or ArcGlobe.  They are typically installed with ArcGIS Desktop so I would imagine you already have them on your machine.  If you don't have the 3D extensions (as mentioned by Brad in the comments) you could try [ArcGIS Explorer](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer/download.html) which is a free viewer for both 2D and 3D data.

Comment: but they will require 3d extensions... http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q800000053000000.htm                                         http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_3D_Analyst/00q8000000wv000000/

Answer (score 1):

Yes ArcGlobe and ArcScene. You will need to build a TIN first using your contours to get an Elevation model then use that model to visualise your mountain.